# Angular: can a controller watch server properties?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns, promise

I have a controller which manages I page of data and a service which makes an HTTP request every 30 seconds to get fresh data to show on the page. I'm trying to write this in an "Angular" way that is testable and leverages the service properly.

I can think of two basic approaches, and I'm guessing one (or maybe both) is wrong:

1. The controller stores the data in a $scope variable, and does a `setInterval` or `$timeout` to call methods of the service to get new data and then update the variable.
2. The service stores the data in it's own variables/property and periodically calls *its self* to get new data. And the controller somehow watches/listens to the service properties to know when to update the view.

For the purposes of this question, it may be helpful to consider a concrete example. If the HTTP request fails, I want to show the error to the view/user. So assume an `errorMsg` variable that needs to live somewhere. Should it live in the controller? In which case, the service needs to return that value every time. Or should it live in the service, and the controller somehow watches for it.

I've tried the first approach, and it seems to result in a LOT of logic in the controller, mostly in `then()`s which follow the service methods. My instinct is that #2 is the correct way to do it. But I'm a little unclear as to *how* the controller should listen/watch the service. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I agree that number 2 is the way to go, but it's a tricky problem. I don't really have help for you at this point, but I can at least offer you some semblance of validation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's look at this from the controller's point of view:

> The controller stores the data and queries the service

This is called **pull**. You are effectively creating a stream of server responses which you're polling in the controller

> The service stores the data and the controller watches it

This is called **push**. You're effectively creating a stream of results and notifying the consumer of changes rather than it looking for them.

---

**Those are both valid approaches for your issue.** Pick the one that you find easier to reason about. Personally I agree that the second is cleaner since you don't have to be aware about it in the controller. This should get you a general idea:

```
function getServerState(onState){
    return $http.get("/serverstate").then(function(res){
        onState(res.data);// notify the watcher
    }).catch(function(e){/*handle errors somehow*/})
      .then(function(){
        return getServerState(onState); // poll again when done call
    });
}
```

Which you can consume like such:

```
getServerState(function(state){
     $scope.foo = state; //since it's in a digest changes will reflect
});
```

Our last issue is that it leaks the scope since the code is not on the controller we have a callback registered to a scope that'll cease to exist. Since we can't use fun ES6 facilities for that yet - we'll have to provide a "I'm done" handle to the getServerState method return value, for example a `.done` property which you'll call on a scope destroy event.

Comment: Thanks!! In the push version, how does the controller know when to check the services data? Is there any equivalent to $watch for this purpose? I was also considering having the service do $rootScope.$broadcast so the controller could listen for updates. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @SDP the function passed to getServerState is the equivalent of `$watch` - you don't need to manually watch for it, the data gets updated (and you know where - in that function you passed it). What our getServerState does here is very similar to a broadcast of an event emitter - I just don't like using rootScope like that since it's global, harder to spot and harder to test but it would also work.

Comment: I'm trying to convert my service to the push approach, but I'm a little stuck. What would the `onState()` function look like?

Comment: @SDP `function(result){ $scope.foo = result; }` for example - it's what you want to run whenever the server gives you state. Note that a more general approach to using push streams might be full blown FRP like baconjs or RxJS - I can show you how if you say it's ok to use them. Note that using something like RxJS is like smiting a fly with a cannon though :)

Comment: Thanks but I'm still missing something. I'm still unclear on how to get the $scope variable to bind to the service variable. I see a lot of different approaches throughout the community.... Some say use `$watch()`. Some say simply: `$scope.foo = Service.bar` should work. And then there's the approach you're offering. Is the last function in the comment above in the controller? Can you maybe update the answer with the new code? Sorry for being slow to understand.

Comment: I figured out how to pass the data back to the controller (I wasn't passing the function to the service as a parameter). The part I'm still fuzzy about is how the updates should work. For example, if the data is meant to refresh every 30 seconds, should the service update its local variable and the controller will automatically update as well? Is that they it should work as written?

Comment: If you have a minute would you care to comment on Gafaar's answer? It's the $rootScope approach which looks very straight forward, but you mentioned it is hard to test. I'm curious to know more of your thoughts on that, and the benefits of your approach.

Comment: Hey,just saw the messages - sorry. I think his answer is what I describe as "pull" in my answer. It's a different mental model. If it works for you that's fine. If you use something similar be wary that it has a serious memory leak - you _must_ listen to the scope destory event and clear the interval. If you don't every time you enter/exit the controller your app will leak more and more memory. I don't think the overhead is particularly big and the push approach can also be made not to make requests to the server unless listeners are attached.

Comment: As for "how it should update" - yes. The function you pass just updates the scope directly. Don't forget to clear it too. To be fair all the other answers at this time just raise points from this one. Allow me to reiterate: there are two approaches _both of them viable_ and you can _pick whichever you find easier to reason about_. There is no clear winner here - it's a subjective design choice you get to make as a software designer.

Comment: Thanks! I prefer your push approach. Can you elaborate on what you just said about "clearing it"? What do I clear?

Comment: Well, the method in the answer is about giving you the _general idea_ for the approach - there are still two things to deal with here: batching (if multiple subscribers subscribe - only make one call at each time) and cancellation: let's say you navigate away from a controller using this method - you need to remove the listener when the scope is destroyed - for example by keeping a handle to the call and cancelling it (like a clearTimeout, sort of). Alternatively you can limit the amount of listeners to one so you have a leak but it's confined to one instance so it's controlled.

Comment: If the service is only consumed by one controller, and it pings the server every 30 seconds forever, do I still need to worry about cancellation?

Comment: No, if it's only one controller and it's constantly there you do not need to worry about it.

Comment: @SDP thanks for accepting - please don't forget to give an answer the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

While Benjamin provided a very nice solution and I totally agree with his answer I would like to add, for the sake of completeness, that there is an other alternative for your problem you maybe did not think of yet:

Using **websockets**.

With websockets your server can call the client directly so you do not need to poll for updates. Of course it depends on your scenario and server technologies whether this would be an option for you at all. But that's how you can create a true **Push** from the server to the client.

If you want to give it a try:

If you are working with .Net servers, then absolutely try [SignalR](http://signalr.net). It is very nice to use and has a fall-back mechanism to long-polling.

There also exists this libray which I did not really use, so I cannot tell a lot: https://github.com/wilk/ng-websocket

Working with node.js you should have a look at [Socket.IO](http://socket.io)

---

Regarding the implementation you can do both implementation but your second option might be cleaner also with web-sockets. That is the way I used to do it so far.

Comment: In addition to the nice answer by @Sjoerd2228888 I would recommend Xsockets.net since that lib has a angular provider for websockets, no dependency to jquery and is faster than signalr.

Comment: @Sjoerd2228888. Using Socket.IO seems to best answer rather than (writing code/worrying) for such kind of update why not use socket.io made for such kind of stuff

Comment: @vijay I did suggest Sockets.IO among other frameworks. I think if OP is working with node.js it is the best option. Working with other server technologies is possible but not so straightforward as far as I know, see  [this question about standalone socket.io](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182631/using-socket-io-standalone-without-node-js) and [this question about socket.io only on client side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506735/client-side-socket-io-without-a-node-js-server)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should keep the logic in the controller (solution #1), because otherwise the service will be running infinitely even if no controller requires it which will cause some memory and network overhead for the entire application. And, I don't think the logic is too complicated for the controller anyway.

Also, passing scope functions to a service does not seem so elegant.

I'd do something like this:

1. service:

> ```
> factory('serverState', ['$http', function($http) {
>     var update = function (){
>        return $http.get("serverUrl")
>     }
>    return {
>     update:update
>    };
>  }]);
> ```

2. controller:

> ```
>     function updateSuccess(res){
>         $scope.state = res.state;
>     }
>
>     function updateFail(res){
>         $scope.state = "Not connected";
>     }
>
>     $interval(function() {
>            serverState.update().then(updateSuccess,updateFail);
>           }, 30000);
> ```

Comment: I originally was doing exactly this. But the logic quickly grows and the controller gets bloated. I have to do a bit of logic with the raw data results... And perhaps the biggest reason I want the logic in the service is that it's much easier to unit test.

Comment: then I'd recommend wrapping all the other logic in another service, but keep the interval in the controller

Answer (score 1):

You can create simple Service (named ServerStateService) which uses $interval to get refresh data from the server every 30 seconds.

```
$interval(function() {
    $http.get(YOUR_URL_PATH).success(function(responseData) {
        $rootScope.$emit('server.state.change', responseData);
    });
}, 30 * 1000);
```

When you get response from the server emit or broadcast the event from ServerStateService named 'server.state.change' with responseData from the server.

And finally handle it from the controller using angular event system.

```
$rootScope.$on('server.state.change', function(data) {
    //Do somethig with data
    $scope.serverData = data;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

While polling the server is a valid method of sharing state between the server and the client, there are other approaches that you can leverage for better performance and less overhead for the server. One of those is mentioned above, WebSockets. WebSockets, however, are fairly new and it would require a good amount of server-side work to support them.

One of the less known or mentioned methods for this is called [Server Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events). It's part of the HTML5 standard and thus you will find all browsers implement it (except, of course, IE. Surprise!). SSE is a surprisingly simple way for the server to alert the client to state changes.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the "Angular" way would be to write a directive.

The directive would contain an isolated scope/child controller. This would allow the two-way binding between controller and your html template file.

When the directive is loaded you would initiate a $timer object which periodically invokes an internal controller
function that would in turn call an angular service (a proxy to your server side data.)

The response data from the service would then be used to update the $scope variable on the controller which is bound to your html template.

This also has the advantage of allowing you to cancel the timer when the directive is removed via the '$destroy' event on the directive scope.

The outline for a solution is below.

```
'use strict';
/*global angular,console,$:false*/

angular.module('testModule').

directive('testDirective', ['testService', function(testService) {


    var testController = function($scope, testService) {
        $scope.testData = {};

        function serviceResponse(data) {
            $scope.testData = data;
        }

        function serviceError(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

        var timeoutPromise = null;

        function startTimer() {
            timeoutPromise = $timeout(function() {

               /* 
                * Call the service, which returns a promise that
                * when resolved will follow the success or error path.
                */
               testService.retrieveData().then(serviceResponse, serviceError);
            }, 180000);  // every 3 minutes
        }

        function cancelTimer() {
            if (timeoutPromise !== null) {
                $timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise);
            }
        }

        $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
            cancelTimer();
        });

        // Start the timer
        startTimer();
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'testHTML.html',
        controller: ['$scope', 'testService', testController],
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    }
  };
}
]);
```